# Check value on merged dataframe and make changes on original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a merged_dataframe which id is from X dataframe and value from Y dataframe
I want to drop rows like A which have value 1 on the last row.
How do I do it so in X dataframe, A rows are dropped?

```
id value
A    0
A    1
B    0
C    0
```

To check the last value in the row, isit by using

```
merged_dataframe = merged_dataframe.groupby('id').nth(-1)
get_last_value = merged_dataframe['value']
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's 1 method of doing it i.e

```
mask = df.groupby('id',as_index=False)['value'].nth(-1) == 1
df.loc[mask[mask].index,'value'] = np.nan
ndf = df.dropna()
```

Output:

```
  id  value
0  A    0.0
2  B    0.0
3  C    0.0
```

If you have a dataframe like

```
   id  value
0  A    1.0
1  A    0.0
2  A    1.0
3  B    1.0
4  B    0.0
5  B    1.0
6  C    0.0
```

Then Output :

```
  id  value
0  A    1.0
1  A    0.0
3  B    1.0
4  B    0.0
6  C    0.0
```